# Не работает ajax или работает не так как надо

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

А может это я туплю. Нужно передать массив в контроллер через ajax. В качестве проверки контроллер возвращает строку из элементов массива. Эту саму строку я хочу вывести при успехе в консоль через тот же аякс запрос, но получается пустая строка. Я что-то делаю не так?

### Контроллер

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string Block(int[] usersId)
        {
            string buf = "";
            foreach (var user in usersId)
            {
                //db.Users.First(u => u.Login == user.Login).IsBlocked = true;
                buf += $"{user}";
            }
            return buf;
            //await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

### Аякс

```
     $("#blocksubmit").click(() => {
        let arr = [];
        ids(arr);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Block',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            dataType: 'text'
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

так вроде заработало

```
$("#blocksubmit").click(() => {
    let arr = [];
    ids(arr);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Block',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'usersId': arr},
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```